# Matplotlib - avoid contour intercepting border

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a contour plot where the contours do not intercept the border of the image. Effectively I would like to add more blue area around the outside contour so that none of the contours intercept the borders.

This is some sample code from [matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_log.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-log-py)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
from matplotlib import ticker, cm

N = 100
x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, N)
y = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, N)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# A low hump with a spike coming out.
# Needs to have z/colour axis on a log scale so we see both hump and spike.
# linear scale only shows the spike.
Z1 = np.exp(-(X)**2 - (Y)**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X * 10)**2 - (Y * 10)**2)
z = Z1 + 50 * Z2

# Put in some negative values (lower left corner) to cause trouble with logs:
z[:5, :5] = -1

# The following is not strictly essential, but it will eliminate
# a warning.  Comment it out to see the warning.
z = ma.masked_where(z <= 0, z)

# Automatic selection of levels works; setting the
# log locator tells contourf to use a log scale:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, z, locator=ticker.LogLocator(), cmap=cm.PuBu_r)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cs)

plt.show()
```

[image: Contours]

As you can see the outside blue contours intercept the border. How to "zoom out" so that none of the contours intercept the border of the image?

Comment: you can change the `locator=ticker.LogLocator()`

Comment: If you do not want a contour line to touch the border, you must ensure the plotted values do not cross a contour threshold along the border. That can mean changing the data you plot, changing the xlims/ylims (so that the data at the border does not cross a threshold), or changing the contour thresholds. Which do you want?

Comment: @Leporello, since the data will change with successive plots, I want the contours to update dynamically. Changing the data is not an option. 
I have tried changing xlim and ylim, but that added a white border around the plot. 
How to dynamically change the contour thresholds so that they do not intercept?

Comment: @serafeim, advice on which ticker will achieve the desired result?

Comment: You can change the `vmin` and `vmax` of the contour so that the last contour is the minimum value along the edges of your matrices...